# wpa_passphrase with hex-encoded SSID

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wpa-supplicant

How can I generate a hex password based on a hex SSID?

**Explanation**

I use the following command to generate a hex value from a unicode string:

```
$ echo -n "→ MyUnicodeSSID ←" | tr -d "\n" | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d " " | tr -d "\n"
--> e28692204d79556e69636f64655353494420e28690
```

However, if I use the hex value for wpa_password I get the following output which uses the hex value as string input:

```
$ wpa_passphrase e28692204d79556e69636f64655353494420e28690 "MySecretPa$$word"

network={
    ssid="e28692204d79556e69636f64655353494420e28690"
    #psk="MySecretPa6100word"
    psk=b4c850a5c05769d9afb828cda94341f734f40aa4bd606a47844ca7f279b55378
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the SSID from the output of `wpa_cli scan` then `wpa_cli scan_results`.  Be sure to use `P` in front of the SSID, i.e.

```
network={
    key_mgmt=NONE
    ssid=P"test\x00abc"
}
```

See:

http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/hostap/2012-August/026461.html

Answer (score 1):

If your `ssid` is `facepalm` , first get hex for the utf8 part:

```
  % echo -n "" | tr -d "\n" | od -A n -t x1 | sed 's/ /\\x/g'
\xf0\x9f\xa4\xa6
```

Then use it as an argument to `wpa_passphrase`:

```
  % wpa_passphrase $'facepalm \xf0\x9f\xa4\xa6' testtest
network={
        ssid="facepalm "
        #psk="testtest"
        psk=99c17bf7e2950d33f9c1c470015487e2cfdfeb6824c9eeb2aab5402880ecd946
}
```

Both `ssid` and `passhprase` are `c`-lang `char`s ([wpa_passphrase.c](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_passphrase.c)).